# Azure APIM - import single controller from an API or split controllers from single API into different APIM APIs

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I have backend APIs with multiple controllers which split up operations which are for 3rd parties, other are for frontend proxies / other micro-services and then there is an support/admin controller. I dont want all of these in the same APIM API / Product.

Currently either having to manually edit the OpenAPI def of the API before importing it into APIM or have to manually create the API in APIM and then using the dev tools extractor to export the templates for other environments.

My stack is

dotnet 5.0 / 6.0 (aspnet) with NSwag to document the API. Using the azure apim development toolkit to automate the bits we can.

I'd like to have a automated pipeline where the backend api is built, have separate OpenAPI defs or way to filter controller during importing, the output from that goes into a pipeline for APIM which then updates the dev environment APIM and then can be auto deployed into other environments when needed.

Does anyone else do this type of thing or do you put the whole API into a single APIM API/Product? Or do you have completely separate backend APIs that make up the a microservice? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I want to share what we do at work.

The key idea is to have a custom OpenAPI processor (be it a command line tool so that you can call that in a pipeline) combined with [OpenAPI Extension specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/). The processor is basically a YAML or JSON parser based on your API spec format.

1. You create a master OpenAPI spec file that contains all the operations in your controller.
2. Create an extension, say *x-api-product: "Product A"*, add this to the relevant API operations.
3. Your custom processor takes in the master spec file (e.g. YAML), and groups the operations by x-api-product then outputs a set of new OpenAPI specs.
4. Import the output files into APIM.

The thing to think about is how you manage the master API spec file. We follow the **API Spec First** approach, where we manually create and modify the YAML file, and use [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to code gen the controllers.

Hope this gives you some ideas.